# Optimizing a SELECT from Oracle to INSERT into SQLite (in Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, cx-oracle

I have an Oracle database that I'm making an extract of a subset of the data into a local SQLite database.  My code is basically the following:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now())

#Oracle portion of the script
sql = '''select [columns] from [table] where [condition]''' 
oracle_cursor.execute(sql)

print(datetime.datetime.now())

#SQLite portion of the script
sqlite_conn.executeany('''INSERT into [table] 
                          ([columns]) 
                          values (?,?,?...etc.)''', 
                          oracle_cursor.fetchall()
                       )
sqlite_conn.commit()
sqlite_conn.close()
```

It does what  need it to, but it takes longer than I would like.  The execution of the Oracle portion is actually surprisingly fast at around 3 minutes. But the inserting takes much longer. I've played around with the SQLite settings like buffer settings, etc. Nothing seems to break 50 rows / second.  There is a spike in network activity for the first three minutes, but once it prints the second datetime from above, there's no network activity, which leads me to believe the bottleneck is something I've coded.  Is my code inefficient at inserting? If so, is there a better way to get what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchall()` loads all data into memory. This is not necessary because `executemany` can work with any iterator; replace `oracle_cursor.fetchall()` with `oracle_cursor`.

Also ensure that you are using a single transaction. (If you have enabled autocommit mode, you should start a transaction explicitly.)

Comment: For others who have this problem:This did slightly speedup write time/line. I looked closer at the network traffic and it turns out that there is an issue between the database and my machine. I just *assumed* that there was no data being transferred. It turns out there was a very *small* amount of data being transferred that didn't show up in the graph of the networking tab in Task Manager.  I discovered this by replacing the insert command with a for loop printing each line in the cursor. This took *exactly* as much per print as per insert, so this is probably the optimal for this scenario.